# Is it possible to break a for loop in bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have the below scenario.
I'm iterating through array elements in bash and comparing the values.

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i = 0 ; i <=m-1 ; i++));

do for (( j = 0 ; j <=n-1 ; j++));

   do

     if [ "${sourcedisktype[i]}" == "SSD" -a "${targetdisktype[j]}" == "BSAS" ];

     then echo "volume cannot be moved1";

     elif [ "${sourcedisktype[i]}" == "SSD" -a "${targetdisktype[j]}" == "SAS" ];

     then echo "volume cannot be moved2";

     elif [ "${sourcedisktype[i]}" == "SAS" -a "${targetdisktype[j]}" == "BSAS" ];

     then echo "volume cannot be moved3";else 
       echo "Volume can be moved for this combination of disk type";done;done;
```

I don't want to execute the else part even if one elif fails. Is there any way to do it. Is it possible to use break statement after elif?

Comment: Indent your code.

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Don't you think your for-loops need a `done`?

Comment: You can either use `continue` to skip the statements remaining in the loop body and start the next iteration, or use `break` to jump out of the current loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can `break` out of your loops in bash, you can actually even break out of `N` nested loops if you use the statement `break N` where `N` is an integer `>=1`.

For more details please have a look at the documentation:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loopcontrol.html

You can actually also use `continue N` but it can be quite tricky and hard for others to understand, so I would not recommend to use it.

PS: do not forget to indent your code properly in order for others to understand it quickly and even for yourself, I can affirm that it will be a pain if you try to reread your code in a couple of months/years. You will regret not having indented/commented it properly.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about break N.